# Quick & dirt CRUD interface to SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, crud

I'm researching software components to use in a future development of a business logic web application. It's gonna be written in Python and we are targeting SQLAlchemy as ORM. The app will be used by other software apps via a REST-like interface over http, possibly using web.py for that part.

For debugging, maintenance, etc we need to directly access the MySQL database but phpmyadmin is too low-level for standard tasks given the rich structure of the db modeled by SQLAlchemy, so I'm looking around for an easy CRUD interface that follows our SA models. It could be a webapp or a local (X11 or whatever) app, and should take as little time as possible to implement.

So far after some googling I've found [Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/) (Qt App) and [RUM](http://python-rum.org/) (WSGI webapp).
Camelot is based over [Elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/), and if we use it in our project too we should be able to share the model definition between our app and Camelot, just adding some camelot specific stuff here and there and we should end up having a Qt interface with little effort.
RUM on the other end seems to be based on [declarative](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/ext/declarative.html), and we should probably base our app on that too to leverage RUM. It's not yet clear to me how much effort should be added to get a working web interface using RUM.

I'd like to know if anyone has experience with Camelot and/or RUM to share, and if using one of the two implies the need to use its declarative layer (either Elixir or, well, declarative) to be able to share the model code without reimplementing it.

Also any other recommendation to get a CRUD interface will be really welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although the Camelot examples are based on Elixir, Camelot is not tied to Elixir, so you could as well use declarative to define your model.  In fact Camelot can be used to display plain old python objects as well.

Comment: We took a look at Camelot and indeed it's really easy to use. Incidentally, we also ended up choosing to use elixir for our project, so adding a camelot gui was a breeze. Bonus: all of Camelot's dependencies are in MacPorts, Camelot itself isn't included but it's pure python so we'll just add its files to our project contents.